# Just navigating to a page with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I want to navigate to my url, I don't need the response or anything.

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequestUtil.CreateHttpWebRequest(url);
```

I can log my navigation from server side and this does not navigate by itself, it just creates the request object.

I can navigate when I create a `ResponseStream` out of the request, but I don't need the response.

Is it possible to `GET` without calling the `GetResponse` method?

Comment: you could just load the reponse into a NullStream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. You need to request the response for the request to be sent.

You could build your own client to use the HTTP protocol directly, and make a special method that doesn't create a `Stream` object to handle the response stream, but the response stream itself always comes back from the server.